# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: No PSK available. Unable to resume

Tags: ssl, networking, java-11

I am using Jetty client to send outgoing requests. Code that runs perfectly under Java 10 suddenly gets the following exception under Java 11:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: No PSK available. Unable to resume.
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:255)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$T13ServerHelloConsumer.consume(ServerHello.java:1224)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$ServerHelloConsumer.onServerHello(ServerHello.java:984)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$ServerHelloConsumer.consume(ServerHello.java:872)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1065)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1052)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.process(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.receive(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpChannelOverHTTP.receive(HttpChannelOverHTTP.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.onFillable(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
```

I filed a bug report with Jetty [here](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2939) but I'm wondering: **what does the error message actually mean?** Is something wrong in my environment or does the error mean that Jetty is not configuring the connection correctly?

Comment: "No PSK Available" means that there was a TLS Session that could be resumed, but there was no Pre-Shared Key present.
That will trigger an INTERNAL_ERROR alert in the OpenJDK implementation side.  So perhaps you have a server producing an incompatible ServerHello block??

Answer (score 88, accepted):

there is a bug in JDK 11: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213202

you have to either:

- wait for the release of JDK 12
- update to JDK 11.0.3+ that includes [backport](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8218095)
- or use this command line parameter as a workaround: `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2`

Comment: Suggest using TLSv1.2 only here if 1.3 is problematic for your Java version.  TLSv1 is deemed dangerous and both 1 and 1.1 are in the process of being "officially" deprecated:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/237688/when-will-tls-1-2-be-deprecated

Comment: For my case, `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3` works.

Answer (score 17):

As Adam from WALCZAK.IT's answer didn't work for me, I found out that the final solution is to add `TLSv1.3` to the `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` in `java.security` file under conf in your java directory.

So, open java.security under `%JAVA_HOME%\conf`, find `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` and append `, TLSv1.3`.

Comment: This worked for me for JDK version "jdk-11.0.2.jdk"

Comment: This worked me for openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25

Comment: This worked me for open jdk-11.0.1

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution that worked for me that add this into your gradle.properties.

```
Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
systemProp.http.proxyHost=fodev.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8118
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.jitpack.io, *.maven.org
systemProp.https.proxyHost=fodev.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8118
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.jitpack.io, *.maven.org
```